# Parent and child $scope with UI Bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scope

I'm making a UI Bootstrap modal window for Firebase e-mail & password login. The modal window logs in the user and returns the `authData` object. The modal window then closes itself. Then the `authData` object is unavailable to the home window or the home controller.

It appears that the modal window or its controller is making a child `$scope`. The `authData` object is available on the child $scope but not on the parent `$scope`.

Here is the button in home.html that executes the code to open the modal window:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="openModal('md')">
   E-mail &amp; password</button>
```

Here is the code in **HomeController.js** that opens the modal window:

```
  $scope.openModal = function(size) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'javascript/templates/emailLoginModalContent.html',
      controller: 'EmailLoginModalInstanceCtrl',
      scope: $scope,
      size: size
    });
  };
```

Note that I set `scope: $scope`. I also tried `scope: $parent`.

Here is part of the modal window's controller:

```
  app.controller('EmailLoginModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $firebaseAuth) {
    console.log("EmailLoginModalInstanceCtrl controller.");

    var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    // Login user

    $scope.loginUser = function(user) {
      ref.authWithPassword({
        email: $scope.user.email,
        password: $scope.user.password
      }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
          console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
          $scope.authData = authData;
          $scope.authData.uid = authData.uid;
          console.log($scope.authData.uid);
          $scope.reset();
          $scope.cancel();
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log("Applied!");
          });
        }
      });
    };

  }]);
```

Note that I tried `$scope.authData = authData;` and  `$scope.authData.uid = authData.uid;`. Neither works to put the `authData` object on the parent $scope.

I also tried running `$getAuth()` from the Home Controller. That got the `authData` object and put it on the parent `$scope`. But I can't get code in Home Controller to execute when the modal window closes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the values from the modal controller to parent controller function like this,

```
  $scope.ok = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.close({ authData : authData})
  }
```

Note, the modal's okay button must call modal controller's `$scope.ok` on `ng-click`.

Now, in your parent controller, $uibModal.open returns an object that contains result property.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'javascript/templates/emailLoginModalContent.html',
      controller: 'EmailLoginModalInstanceCtrl',
      scope: $scope,
      size: size
    })
modalInstance.result.then(function(authData){
  console.log('printing authData - ', authData)
})
```

Comment: ^this is the way. 

You can also pass into the modal instance a callback function to access the scope for variable in $uibModal... which is nice, by adding resolve. 

var callingFn = function(){ //do stuff };

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    size: size,
    templateUrl: //..etc.
    resolve: { passFn: callingFn}

Comment: Right answer! :-)  Now I see ```close(result)``` in the documentation. Thanks!